# Telegraf call action from hears text

Tags: telegram-bot, telegraf

How can I call from the capture of a text to a concrete action

```
bot.command('/help', ctx => {
    const helpMessage = `
        *Help Bot* 
        /start - start
        /remove - delete
        /help - help
    `
    bot.telegram.sendMessage(ctx.from.id, helpMessage, {
        parse_mode: 'Markdown'
    })
})

bot.hears('help', (ctx) => {
    //command /help    
});
```

Thanks

```
run action /help when user types help
```

Answer (score 0):

bot.hears should be higher bot.command